# JQuery script conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery Lightbox for a gallery on a page with a jQuery Slideshow and menu bar, whilst the menu bar and Slideshow work ok, the Lightbox does not.

CONFLICT WITH LIGHTBOX
see http://concertorestaurant.creativeconnect.com.au/functions_gallery.html

WORKING EXAMPLE - Menu with Slideshow
http://concertorestaurant.creativeconnect.com.au/home.html

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think one of your JavaScript files and several of your other files are in the wrong place, errors from Chrome:

```
style-projects-jquery.css: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (ERROR: The file requested could not be found.)
SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (ERROR: The file requested could not be found.)
PLHIM1.js: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (ERROR: The file requested could not be found.)
functions_gallery.html:16: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'lightBox'
thumb_image2.jpg: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (ERROR: The file requested could not be found.)
```

Check out the third and fourth lines in particular.

Answer (score 0):

First check the error on your page

```
    Webpage error details

    User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GIS IE 6.0 Build 20080321; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; MS-RTC LM 8; GIS IE 6.0 Build 20080321)
    Timestamp: Wed, 9 Feb 2011 05:53:39 UTC


    Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
    Line: 16
    Char: 9
    Code: 0
    URI: http://concertorestaurant.creativeconnect.com.au/functions_gallery.html
```